# Issue in removing layer from keras surgeon

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pruning

I am trying to remove a layer using kerassurgeon however I am facing issue to do I tried different ways but none of themworking.

```
# delete layer_1 from a model
from kerassurgeon import Surgeon
surgeon = Surgeon(vgg_model)
surgeon.add_job('delete_layer', layer_1)
new_model = surgeon.operate()
```

Error

```
 NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-9-dabc597cba5b> in <module>()
  2 from kerassurgeon import Surgeon
  3 surgeon = Surgeon(vgg_model)
->4 surgeon.add_job('delete_layer', layer_1)
  5 new_model = surgeon.operate()
  NameError: name 'layer_1' is not defined


  from kerassurgeon.operations import delete_layer
  # delete layer_1 from a model
  model = delete_layer(vgg_model, layer_1)
```

Error

```
   1 from kerassurgeon.operations import delete_layer
   2 # delete layer_1 from a model
 ->3 model = delete_layer(vgg_model, layer_1)
  NameError: name 'layer_1' is not defined

  # or kerassurgeon for standalone Keras
  from tfkerassurgeon import delete_layer
  model = delete_layer(vgg_model.layers[0])
```

Error

```
   1 # or kerassurgeon for standalone Keras
-> 2 from tfkerassurgeon import delete_layer, insert_layer
   3 
   4 model = delete_layer(vgg_model.layers[0])
   ImportError: cannot import name 'delete_layer' from 'tfkerassurgeon' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tfkerassurgeon/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing this issue however I checked GitHub (https://github.com/BenWhetton/keras-surgeon), just change

this:

```
from kerassurgeon import delete_layer, insert_layer
```

to:

```
from kerassurgeon.operations import delete_layer, insert_layer
```

To prevent module import error I would recommend downloading every package how it is written in the original website or GitHub, readme file.